# Crystal Reports through visual studio age error message

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to calculate age in Crystal Reports through visual studio (very weak with visual studio but I'm trying to learn it) and after lots of searching, haven't figured out why I'm getting an error and none of the questions on here helped.
[My current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBrpZ.png)

I've done age successfully before, so I'm assuming it was the format. [My sql results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wUEN.png)

I tried DateDiff ('yyyy', {Employee.BirthDate},CurrentDate ) but an error popped up that I needed a date.
Tried Cdate (ToText({Employee.BirthDate}, 'MM/dd/yyyy')) [but got this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4ijN.png)

Any help or resources would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this one works,

```
datediff('yyyy',{Employee.BirthDate} ,currentdate)-(if datepart('y',currentdate)>datepart('y',{Employee.BirthDate}) then 0 else 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I think the problem is the database itself. The birthdate is a date format but for some reason, anything I tried with it did not work. Your solution worked on another database I tested but not the one I was tinkering with.